# Create a custom detail view for a collection view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

How to format a detail view for a UICollectionView when choosing images that looks as fancy like this?

```
<blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/FQ4Vj"><a href="//imgur.com/FQ4Vj"></a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I have been trying to figure it out for a long time now but can't understand how they do it. I've noticed that the second view is some kind of library but how do they do it without pushing to a new view controller and keeping it all in the same hierarchy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a great solution using this library:
https://github.com/recruit-mp/RMPZoomTransitionAnimator
this combined with a TableView using a Parallax header creates the effect wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You may look for something like this:

https://github.com/freedom27/PopInAndOutCollectionViewTransition

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, is there a similar one for Objective C?

Comment: Not sure. But if you look for a similar logic, you can follow this tutorial, even if in swift: http://zappdesigntemplates.com/uiviewcontroller-transition-from-uicollectionviewcell/